# NetBeans: fix import does not add standard java classes any more

Tags: java, netbeans

I noticed that my installation of Netbeans 19 stopped to automatically add imports for classes in the jdk when I do a "Fix imports". It works for classes in other jars. Does anyone knwo what this should be due to?

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 19
Java: 19.0.2; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04
System: Linux version 6.5.6-76060506-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_GB (nb)
User directory: /home/ste/.netbeans/19
Cache directory: /home/ste/.cache/netbeans/19
```

UPDATE:
If I delete .netbeans/19 it works (of course loosing all customizations). I found this error message in var/log/messages.log:

> Even though the source level of
> /home/ste/Projects/uzz/src/main/java:/home/ste/Projects/uzz/src/main/resources
> is set to: 19, java.lang.AssertionError cannot be found on the
> bootclasspath:

Can this be related?

Comment: Try to delete the cache. The location of the cache folder can be found under Help / About.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimRohde, it did not make any difference. I have updated the description with the details provided by the about box.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, I am replying to my own question as other may incur in the same issue.

The problem was that I had multiple JDK19 platform configured, one of those was not even available. I guess this generated the conflict as per the message. Removing all unwanted JDK19 platforms and restarting fixed the problem.